# Rank groups based on order

Tags: oracle, gaps-and-islands

```
     A          B          C
     1        132          1 
     1        155          2 
     1        132          3 
     1        132          4 
     1        155          5
     1        155          6 
     1        132          7

select A, B, [...] as D
from myTable
order by C
```

Query must be ordered by C and should return:

```
     A          B          D
     1        132          1 
     1        155          2
     1        132          3 
     1        132          3 
     1        155          4
     1        155          4
     1        132          5
```

All A and B pair groups must have unique D value.

Is it possible to calculate some kind of ID for groups based on order ?

Tried with RANK and GROUPING SETS but with not success.

Comment: Try using rownum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the data, order by `C`.
Compute a temporary column: if `B` equals to `B` in the previous row (rows ordered by `C`), let that column be `0`, otherwise `1`. This column is used for the following: when `B` is the same as `B` in the previous row, we increase the value in `D` by `0`, otherwise we increase the value by `1`. Finally, get `A`, `B`, and the `SUM` of the temporary column up to the current row (this requires the analytic version of `SUM`), this will give us `D`.

The above translated to SQL:

```
with data as
(
  select 1 a, 132 b, 1 c from dual union all
  select 1 a, 155 b, 2 c from dual union all
  select 1 a, 132 b, 3 c from dual union all
  select 1 a, 132 b, 4 c from dual union all
  select 1 a, 155 b, 5 c from dual union all
  select 1 a, 155 b, 6 c from dual union all
  select 1 a, 132 b, 7 c from dual 
)
select * from data order by c;

         A          B          C
---------- ---------- ----------
         1        132          1
         1        155          2
         1        132          3
         1        132          4
         1        155          5
         1        155          6
         1        132          7
```

Get the expected result:

```
with data as
(
  select 1 a, 132 b, 1 c from dual union all
  select 1 a, 155 b, 2 c from dual union all
  select 1 a, 132 b, 3 c from dual union all
  select 1 a, 132 b, 4 c from dual union all
  select 1 a, 155 b, 5 c from dual union all
  select 1 a, 155 b, 6 c from dual union all
  select 1 a, 132 b, 7 c from dual 
)
select
  a, b,
  sum(d) over (order by c rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as d
from
(
select
  a, b, c,
  case when lag(b) over (order by c) = b
    then 0
    else 1
  end as d
from
  data
)
order by c
;

         A          B          D
---------- ---------- ----------
         1        132          1
         1        155          2
         1        132          3
         1        132          3
         1        155          4
         1        155          4
         1        132          5
```